# How to prevent user access to IP address for a website hosted in GCP?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, ip-address, cloudflare, bitnami

I have a Wordpress website (Bitnami) thats hosted in Google Cloud Platform. The IP address is something like: `33.33.33.33`. My domain is hosted on Google Domains and has 2 nameservers pointing to Cloudflare. On the Cloudflare DNS settings, I have 2 A records, one is ftp and the other is something like 'mywebsite.com'. I also have a `CNAME` which is www mywebsite.com.

I am able to hit the full URL of my website but I also notice I can enter the IP address and it also works and loads the website. Is it possible to prevent acccess to `33.33.33.33` and only allow the full URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create VPC Firewall Rules that only allow Cloudflare IP addresses.

Consult this [document](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) for the current Cloudflare IP list.

[Google Cloud VPC firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

Note: Cloudflare does not support FTP, so you must point your DNS resource record for FTP to your server's IP address and not through Cloudflare. I recommend that you do not use FTP. Use SSH/SFTP for file transfers. Configure WordPress so that installing plugins, uploading images, etc do not require FTP. FTP is not encrypted which means your login username and password are sent in the clear.

Comment: For best practices, should I create firewall rules for TCP only or should I also create it for UDP and ICMP?

Comment: @TCman4585 - Allow TCP ingress only on port 80/443 from Cloudflare. Do not modify egress rules. Cloudflare proxies HTTP/HTTPS traffic which is a layer above TCP. Deny all UDP and ICMP ingress traffic.

Comment: May I point out that, while significantly unlikely, an attacker could still bypass your Cloudflare protections by proxying their malicious requests though their own Cloudflare project in some way (Workers or something) and your firewall would allow the requests as they come from "any Cloudflare server" not necessarily your own site.

Comment: @Brett - you are correct and that is an important security item to review.